# 'let' in for loop with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

```
let timer = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
    }, i * 1000)
  }
}
timer();
```

code above will print 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in 1000ms interval
and if I change `let i = 0` into `var i = 0`, `timer()` will pring '5' five times in 1000ms interval. So far so good, and I know the differences between `let` and `var`
But now I want to print 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in 1000ms interval, **and not using** `let` keyword, so what should I do?
 I think I might need to use closure, but I don't know how.
edit: by not using let I mean use `var` instead

Comment: If not `let` or `var`... are you trying to use `const`? I guess I'm not sure what the goal is in not using `let`.

Comment: @stealththeninja probably to avoid using ES6+

Comment: @stealththeninja I mean just use `var`

Comment: [Another way](https://repl.it/repls/LongtermRigidLock) using recursion and no simultaneous timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use `let`, you can always use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression):

```js
let timer = () => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (i => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i)
      }, i * 1000)
    })(i)
  }
}
timer();
```

If you're trying to make your code ES5-compatible, you've got to turn the arrow functions into normal functions as well:

```js
var timer = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function (i) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
      }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
  }
}
timer();
```